# Optimization to minimize cost function

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have the function $C=Tq^{\frac 1a }+F$. Where $C$ is total cost, $q$ is output, $a$ is a positive parametric constant, $F$ is fixed cost, and $T$ measures the technology available to the firm (Parameter). We also know that $T\gt 0$.

A hint is to use calculus of optimization, and to check our second-order condition.

I got the answer of it being convex with the function of $T(\frac 1a )^{\frac 1a−1}Q^{\frac 1a-2 }$
However I can't figure out the rest:

Assuming $a\lt 0.5$, and by using optimization what is the value of $q$ that minimizes the average cost?

Hint: the answer for $q$ will be in the parameters of the model, be sure to check the second order condition.

I found the first function but I don't know how to apply optimization towards it.

Comment: Your function is not clear. Is the exponent $1/a$?  Does the exponent apply to just $Q$ or to $TQ$? You should use $\LaTeX$ or add more parentheses to your function definition.

Comment: I edited it, the exponent is 1/a, where the a<0.5. The exponent of 1/a only applies to the q. Does that help?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: I attempted to fix your formatting.  If my edit is accepted, check to see if it is still correct.

Comment: Thank you for the editing help, I just changed the edited back one of the formulas

Comment: What is the independent variable: $T$? Are $q$, $a$, and $F$ all constants or are they dependent on the variable? If, as it appears in your description, they are constants, the derivative is simply $dC/dT=q^{1/a}$. And what do you mean by "convex with the function of..."?

Comment: Wouldn't the independent variable be q since every other variable has a constraint on it, and it is the quantity of q that minimizes the average cost?